# Update polyline in flutter as google does it in Google Maps App

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-directions-api, google-maps-flutter

Current, i'm implement tracking + navigation to specific point by updating polyline on change of current location.  this process is very costly because it calling direction Api on every new location. I want to update polyline by calling one time google direction api and then update it statically or as google uses it in google maps app.

**Try Start Navigation Function**

it looks like this

```
  startNavigation() async {
    var pickUp = await getBytesFromAsset(AppIcons.navMarker, 80, 80);
    var dest = await getBytesFromAsset(AppImages.destMarker, 40, 40);

    location.changeSettings(
      accuracy: LocationAccuracy.navigation,
    );
    location.enableBackgroundMode(enable: true);
    timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timerValue) {
      timer = timerValue;
      location.getLocation().then((l) async {
        pickLatitude.value = l.latitude!;
        pickLongitude.value = l.longitude!;
      
        if (isNavigationStarted.value == true) {

          await getPolyline().then((value) {
            markers.clear();
            cameraZoom.value = 18;
            Set<Circle> circles2 = {
              Circle(
                circleId: const CircleId("dsd"),
                center: LatLng(l.latitude!, l.longitude!),
                fillColor: Colors.blue.shade100.withOpacity(0.5),
                strokeColor: Colors.blue.shade100.withOpacity(0.1),
                radius: 20,
              )
            };
            circles.value = circles2;
            addMarker(
              position: LatLng(l.latitude!, l.longitude!),
              id: "pickup",
              rotation: l.heading!,
              descriptor: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(pickUp),
              anchor: const Offset(0.5, 0.5),
            );
            addMarker(
              position: LatLng(destination.center.latitude.toDouble(),
                  destination.center.longitude.toDouble()),
              id: "dest",
              rotation: l.heading!,
              descriptor: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(dest),
              anchor: const Offset(0.5, 0.5),
            );

            updateCameraPositionForNavigation();
            var difference = distanceBetweenLatLng(
                LatLng(l.latitude!, l.longitude!),
                LatLng(destination.center.latitude.toDouble(),
                    destination.center.longitude.toDouble()));
          });
        } else {
          markers.clear();
          cameraZoom.value = 18;
          Set<Circle> circles2 = {
            Circle(
              circleId: const CircleId("dsd"),
              center: LatLng(l.latitude!, l.longitude!),
              fillColor: Colors.blue.shade100.withOpacity(0.5),
              strokeColor: Colors.blue.shade100.withOpacity(0.1),
              radius: 20,
            )
          };
          circles.value = circles2;
          addMarker(
            position: LatLng(l.latitude!, l.longitude!),
            id: "pickup",
            rotation: l.heading!,
            descriptor: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(pickUp),
            anchor: const Offset(0.5, 0.5),
          );
          updateCameraPostionBasedOnVisibility();
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

**Expected**

Google like Navigation + tracking which lower the cost of direction Api